# omission of に when its used with もらう

Tags: grammar, particle-に, giving-and-receiving

デンジ君は早川君の部隊に入ってもらう

デンジ君**に**は早川君の部隊に入ってもらう

Any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning.

Grammatically the subject/topic of the first sentence is デンジ君 and the subject of the second is the implicit *I*. Thus they roughly correspond to

1. Denji shall be in Hayakawa's unit.
2. I will let Denji join Hayakawa's unit.

In both sentences, もらう indicates the speaker benefits from Denji's joining the unit.